# I am have trouble understanding which parameters to include in which methods

Tags: python, class, oop, python-class

I'm working through a chapter on classes and I'm having trouble understanding which parameters to include in which methods. For example in this code:

```
class Employee:
    '''A simple class to describe an employee.'''

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary, sal_raise=5000):
        '''Initialize first name, last name, salary, and maybe raise?'''
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.salary = salary
        self.sal_raise = sal_raise

    def give_raise(self):
        self.salary += self.sal_raise
        print(f'''You've given {self.first_name} a ${self.sal_raise} raise!''')
```

`sal_raise` is currently a parameter in the `__init__()` method. Is this the only way to do it? Is it not possible instead initialize sal_raise in the give_raise method? Something like this:

```
def give_raise(self):
    self.sal_raise = 5000
    self.salary += self.sal_raise
```

Comment: Yes that's absolutely fine although `self.salary += 5000` is more concise. Or add it as a default parameter for the `give_raise` method.

Comment: It would probably make more sense to have the raise amount be a parameter to `give_raise()`, so that you aren't stuck with a single raise amount for the employee.

Comment: It is fine, except that if you do what you suggest Marcin then the `sal_raise` attribute of your Employee object will always be 5000 when you want to give a raise.  In other words, everytime you want to `give_raise()`, the raise will always be 5000.  Doing it the other way or doing as @jasonharper suggests will at least allow you to change the raise amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you know what is the difference between `__init__()` method and other methods defined inside the class ? Nothing ! the only difference is `__init__()` "automatically" gets called when the class is instantiated.

What is the benefit ? image you don't have `__init__()`, in order do set some initial value for your instance you have to call a method explicitly:

```
class Person:

    def initialize_my_class(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 10
        self.height = 100

p1 = Person()

print(p1.name)    #  AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'name'
print(p1.age)     #  AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'age'
print(p1.height)  #  AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'height'
```

Why ? because python doesn't automatically run my `initialize_my_class` method. If I want this to work, I have to call it myself :

```
class Person:

    def initialize_my_class(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 10
        self.height = 100

p1 = Person()

p1.initialize_my_class('Soroush')  # <---------- Here

print(p1.name)
print(p1.age)
print(p1.height)
```

`__init__()` just does this automatically. Imagine you have tens of methods inside your class, without `__init__()` you have to call each of them one after the other... But instead we just do everything we want for initialization inside `__init__()`.

Now your `sal_raise` : Generally, If this is something that you need it in initialization part, define it inside `__init__()`. **But** sometimes we want our instance to have an attribute "whenever" we want ! not at the initialization phase. why ?

Sometimes we have to calculate something that is heavy enough or time consuming(not just storing a number), we set that attribute to our instance in a separate method and we call it when is necessary! maybe when a program reaches to a certain condition. So just let `__init__` to include other initializations that is necessary for us in instantiating phase :

```
class Person:

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.age = 10
        self.height = 100
        
    def time_consuming_method(self):
        # This 'foo' is the result of heavy calculation here
        self.new_var = 'foo'

p1 = Person('soroush')

# special condition is true...
# Now it's time to call 'time_consuming_method':
p1.time_consuming_method()
```

Hope that makes sense.

Comment: Thank you! This was extremely informative!

Answer (score 0):

In this situation it is likely that the amount to raise the salary by would be different each time. So you wouldn't want to set it once at initialisation or have it as an unchanging value.

Instead, you can have the raise as a parameter to `give_raise`:

```py
class Employee:

    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, salary):
        self.first_name = first_name
        self.last_name = last_name
        self.salary = salary

    def give_raise(self, sal_raise):
        self.salary += sal_raise
        print(f'''You've given {self.first_name} a £{sal_raise} raise!''')
        print(f'''{self.first_name}'s salary is now £{self.salary}!''')


robson = Employee("Robson", "Moon", 100000)
robson.give_raise(5000)
robson.give_raise(2000)
```

That will output:

```
You've given Robson a £5000 raise!
Robson's salary is now £105000
You've given Robson a £2000 raise!
Robson's salary is now £107000
```